# Scrollview didn't scrolling after dismissViewControllerAnimated

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I'm calling a view controller from my mainScreen with the following code:

```
VisualizarFotoViewController *visualizarFoto = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"VisualizarFoto"];
[self presentViewController:visualizarFoto animated:NO completion:^{
    [UIImageView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
        visualizarFoto.visualizarFoto.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
        visualizarFoto.visualizarFoto.image = _fotoPrincipal.image;
        visualizarFoto.viewPrincipal.alpha = 1;
        visualizarFoto.telaOrigem = 2;

    }];
}];
```

To come back to the mainScreen I dismiss the view controller with the following code:

```
[UIImageView animateWithDuration:0.2 animations:^{
    _viewPrincipal.alpha = 0;
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
}];
```

My issue is that when I come back to the mainScreen, my scrollview doesn't answer to any scrolling gesture. I've tried to use `[_scrollView becomeFirstResponder]` in `viewDidAppear` section but with no success.
Do you have any hint to solve this please?
Thanks

Comment: Do any of the other controls on the mains screen work?  If not, it would appear that the viewPrincipal or some other object is still getting events.

Comment: All the controls works fine, including those that are inside the scrollview... it just don't scroll.

Comment: Put a log in viewDidAppear to check the contentSize of the scroll view to see if it changes after you switch view controllers.

Comment: It shows the right size: 960 when I switch back.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If is there someone looking for an answer, this is what I did to solve this issue:

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    // Define the scrollview size accordingly with the number of pages
    [_scrollView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 43, 320, 450)];
    [_scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320 * 3, 450)];
}
```

Comment: YOU SAVED MY LIFE! ...My issue was caused by presentViewController resizing my view. This overrode apple's code and gave me my view back...I'm very happy!

Comment: Thanks. I was banging my head against the wall with this one. I had an identical case, except that my scrollview worked on a 4 inch device but not on 3.5 inch device. Same strange behaviour on simulator.